for loop and if else
df_test2 <- data.frame(test1=c("in", "out"), test2=c(1:2))

> df_test2
  test1 test2
1    in     1
2   out     2

for (i in df_test2$test1) {
  for (j in df_test2$test2) {
    if (i="in") {
      print(j + 1)
    } else {
      print(j - 1)
    }
  }

I ran the above code and nothing returned while I was expecting see the outcome being 2 and 1. Mind telling if I am using the wrong loop technique?

I would do it without a for loop
> with(df_test2, ifelse(test1 == "in", test2+1, test2-1))
[1] 2 1

Note that = is an assignment operator equivalent to <- and you want to do a logical comparison, so you should use == instead.
If you want for whatever reason a for loop, then you can write it using just one index for selecting rows:
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df_test2))){
  if(df_test2[i, 1] == "in"){
    print(df_test2[i, 2] + 1)
  } else {
    print(df_test2[i, 2] - 1)
  }
}


If you do want to use a for loop, here is the correct way to do so in R:
df_test2<-data.frame(test1=c("in","out"),
                 test2=c(1:2))

for(i in 1:nrow(df_test2)) {
  if(df_test2[i, "test1"] == "in") {
    print(df_test2[i, "test2"] + 1)
  } else {
    print(df_test2[i, "test2"] - 1)
  }
}

Loop through the dataframe rows by iterating i over a range of values (1 to the number of rows).
Now we can use df_test2[i, "column_name_here"] to refer to a value in that [row, col].
Also make sure to use double equals signs in if statements. Single equals signs assign a value, double equals signs compare values.
